# A fragment bundle cannot be started: initial@reference:file:com.springsource.org.apache.jasper-6.0.18.jar

Tags: osgi, equinox, springsource-dm-server

I am developing a sping dynamic modules on Equinox. However when I run Equinox I have several bundles in RESOLVED state. One of these is `com.springsource.org.apache.jasper-6.0.18.jar`. Then, when I try to start it Equinox returns an error as:

> A fragment bundle cannot be started: initial@reference:file:com.springsource.org.apache.jasper-6.0.18.jar

I do not what is the cause. Does anyone know the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi
For me it looks that you try to start a 'fragment bundle'. Fragment bundles can not be started so you see this error. 
As soon as the host plugin 'bundle' of the fragment is started, the osgi framework will attach the fragment to it (automatically).